# Convert POST to GET Azure API Management Rest API

Tags: azure-api-management

I am using Azure API Management REST API's to import a WSDL and convert it to a REST endpoint calling SOAP backend.

However when you import the WSDL all the methods are imported as POST (which makes sense since you need to send the soap envelope). Now I want to convert the operation from POST to GET via the REST API (which I can do through portal).

Has anyone tried that before, and if yes which API's should I call?

Answer (score 1):

For this case I used a public soap service:
https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/numberconversion.wso?op=NumberToDollars

I [imported this SOAP service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-soap-api)  to API Management:

[image]

Request-Body:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <Body>
    <NumberToDollars xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/">
      <dNum>1</dNum>
    </NumberToDollars>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

The *NumberToDollars* operation has to read the XML, transform it into JSON, and pass the data to a [GET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#SetRequestMethod) API.

For testing purposes I created an mocked Operation which returns 200:
https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net/echo/200/test

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="num" value="@{
            string xml = context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true);
            xml = Regex.Unescape(xml);

            // Remove the double quotes
            xml = xml.Remove(0,1);
            xml = xml.Remove(xml.Length-1,1);

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);

            var data = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc));
            JObject envelope = data["Envelope"] as JObject;
            JObject body = envelope["Body"] as JObject;
            JObject numberToDollars = body["NumberToDollars"] as JObject;

            return numberToDollars["dNum"].Value<string>();
            }" />
        <set-method>GET</set-method>
        <set-backend-service base-url="https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net/echo/200/" />
        <rewrite-uri template="@("/test?q=" + context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("num"))" copy-unmatched-params="false" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Testing the operation:
[image]

The trace log:
[image]

The JSON document generated from XML:

```json
{
  "?xml": {
    "@version": "1.0",
    "@encoding": "utf-8"
  },
  "Envelope": {
    "@xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope",
    "Body": {
      "NumberToDollars": {
        "@xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
        "@xmlns": "http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/",
        "dNum": "1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```